# Using PUT http method from Velocity/HTML form in Spark/Java

Tags: java, postgresql, http, velocity, spark-framework

utI have a Spark/Velocity template application and I am trying to use the PUT route to follow good REST conventions for updating a record in my DB.

In my HTML form, I get the information I need to update a record in my postgres DB:

```
<form action="/tasks/$editTask.getId()">
  <input id="description" name="description" type="text" value="$editTask.getDescription()">
  <input type="date" name="duedate" value="$editTask.getDueDate()">
  <button type="submit">Edit task</button>
</form>
```

But I am confused about how to capture this in my App. java. If I change the method `method="PUT"` nothing happens. Below is my PUT route:

```
post("/tasks/:id", (request,response) -> {
    HashMap<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.params("id"));
    Task editTask = Task.find(id);
    String newDescription = request.queryParams("description");
    String newDueDate = request.queryParams("duedate");

    editTask.update(newDescription, newDueDate);
    model.put("editTask", editTask);
    model.put("template", "templates/tasks.vtl");
    return new ModelAndView(model, layout);
}, new VelocityTemplateEngine());
```

I have tried adding a hidden input field:

`<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">` to my form but it doesnt do anything. I don't get any kind of error when I try and access the put route, just nothing happens. I have tested my code to update records on the POST route and it works without a hitch.

Thank you so much for any pointers on how to use PUT, as 
I think I will have the same problem using DELETE etc.